# list_filter in django admin page for foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

use foreign fields in list_filter of django admin page

Suppose i have models

```
   class Company():
         name varchar(50)
         field1 varchar(50)

   class Client()
          name varchar(50)
          company ForeignKey(Company)
```

Now how can i implement filter on Client model for field1 in django admin page

I tried **list_filter = ['company_*field1', 'company*_name']** but didn't work. Any solutions?

I'm using django 1.2 version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

This can't be done in Django 1.2.

Starting with 1.3 you can use that standard `relatedModel__field' syntax (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)). Note that you have to use a double underscore for this to work.

In the current [dev version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) you could to even more complex things be using a subclass of `SimpleListFilter` which pratically allows you to do anything you like ;)

Answer (score 4):

With Django 1.2, there is a hacky work around I've used for this sort of thing.

In your database, define a view on a join of the two tables with the foreign key relationship.  Then make Django use the view instead of the real table.  Put triggers on the view to redirect database writes to the correct table.